# Android - Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps, ant, android-emulator

I've the same issue which I've realized most people have had here...But I can't succeed when I tried to fix it using solutions provided on any thread.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml (I guess there's no problem here - I know there's some unused permissions don't pay any attention):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.acilSRV.client"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity android:name=".AcilActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>    
</manifest>
```

My main.xml(I've rechecked api key several times and it works for **debug.keystore**):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Address info" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:id="@+id/txt_addressinfo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    />

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="****"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

So these are the core configurations, and I guess you must agree that there's no problem with the codes above...But why then I get "Couldn't get connection factory client" error message when I run application - I have my Map look (that proves the api key legality), but when I use *geo fix*   to give different location that return me LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE which I guess I'm getting because of the above error message...

I'm using Ant for building and Google Maps revision 10 api... Any suggestion about this weird case? Can it be caused because of debug.keystore keystore file? Do I have to test another keystore file?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is not in your code...but it's somewhere else...
Maybe you can see this one if you have'nt :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006835/android-mapactivity-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client) or
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

I also got that problem too..those link's can give you some information's about the problem
Good luck :D