# MapActivity "couldn't get connection factory client"

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I'm programming a Google Maps based Android application. The application itself runs fine, without any issues. I can see the map, zoom to my current location etc. etc. All permissions should be fine according to the AndroidManifest.xml. I also have an API key for the map which is working. When the map is loaded I get the above mentioned error. I've searched the Internet and it seems to be an API bug. I would really like to get this confirmed by someone who maybe has had the same problem. If it is possible to fix the issue, it would be preferred of course.

I  hope that someone can confirm that this is just an API bug or maybe has some fix to the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006835/android-mapactivity-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client

Comment: see this post maybe helpful [Couldn't get connection factory client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client)

Comment: @harish I'm sorry but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @imrankhan I have also looked into your solution. But unfortunately its not what I need, though it says that it might be an API error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is an API error or not. But I can tell you one thing, I have 3 real Apps based on Maps and I see this error all the time, it never hurts if that what you need to know. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am going to confirm.  I get this error as well with functioning apps, in my MapActivity, and it doesn't seem to do any harm.  That said, I have not been able to track down the source leading me to believe it is in fact an API bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it has same issue, when I put some code to get location provider with fine accuracy. Emulator did Samsung Galaxy 2 as well.

```
    Crieteria mCriteria;

    if (mCriteria==null){
        mCriteria = new Criteria();
        mCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    }

    return mManager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, true);
```

So, I removed the code and it did work fine again. I hope this would be helpful.