# MapView: Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android Application I have a Google MapView Activity and I am facing the following Error:

```
MapView: Couldn't get connection factory client
```

At first: I have a right Maps Key and the Internetpermission and the Map is displaying fine on Emulator and Device. The thing that I am confused about is that although the map works, the above error displays.

On the Device sometimes the Map loads and displays correctly and 1 minute later, if start to zoom and pinch the map the map does not continue loading and throws the error.

If I switch off and on again the mobile network on the device the map works fine again.

Edit: my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.incowia.mobileschatzsuche" 
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="2011.10.07">

<!-- We're supporting AndroidSDK 7 -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>

<!-- We need access to the internet for loading maps -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- We're using both, network and GPS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme">

    <!-- 4 test -->
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

    <!-- We're using Google Maps API -->
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <!-- Dashboard -->
    <activity android:name=".MobileSchatzsucheActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Maps Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".GoogleMapsActivity" />

    <!-- Schatzliste Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".SchatzlisteActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

    <!-- Schatzdetails Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"/>

    <!-- MyTreasuresCoverFlowActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".MyTreasuresCoverFlowActivity"/>

    <!-- Preferences Activity-->
    <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme"/>

    <!-- FileBrowser Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".FileBrowserActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme"/>

</application>

<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="de.incowia.mobileschatzsuche" 
    android:label="test test" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9989518/593709) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2199403/593709)

Comment: aste your manifeast file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to give these Two Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Because when you zoom in/zoom out the Google map goes accordingly in/out, so for that we need to give such permission.
It will work then

Comment: I already have this two permissions in my Manifest file but the Error is still there.