# Showing error in mapview Android

Tags: android

I want to display three pin points in the mapview and i had checked the internet connections in the emulator and even i had used the key for displaying mapview but it's showing error couldn't get connection factory client.

Answer (score 0):

Basic info for displaying map in your Android Application.

```
1. Your application build platform is Google-Api not Android-Api.

2. put <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in Application tag in
   Android manifest file.

3. Your mapview activity must extend MapActivity.

4. You have a your system specific map-key for debug version of application.
```

Comment: yes i did all this but then too i am not getting what the problem is i got the pinpoints but unable to display mapview

Comment: And your emulator also build in Google-Api.

Comment: Forgot about error could'nt get connection factory client have you seen you mapview correctly?

Comment: no i got the pin points displayed but no mapview it just shows the gridview with square boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these two Permissions also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

It can be because of Map getting Zoom it. And you can refer to this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client).

Comment: I had added this also but nothing works in displaying mapview

Comment: @user1266179 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006835/android-mapactivity-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client Refer this link.

Comment: i saw this but i had done everything then too facing this problem now what to do its just showing could'nt get connection factory client

Comment: Try this site i solved my problem from here only and there is an example also of multiple Pin. http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android17MapView.php#Google%20Map%20View%20with%20Overlay

Comment: i did the same as shown in this but then too same error could'nt find the connection factory client

Comment: Try to Clean your project, and if it dosen't occur then just download .zip file from there and work on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9854/discussion-between-user1266179-and-dev)