# getting null on current location on Samsung Galaxy Grand android?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm try to run my app on  Samsung Galaxy Grand but its not showing my current location.

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    System.out.println("provider => " + provider);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    System.out.println("location  " + location);
```

but always this line return null **locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);** but this app works fine in other phones like **sony and lg**.

i have try so many link but still same problem.

[getLastKnownLocation() always returning null, all providers are DummyLocationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894162/getlastknownlocation-always-returning-null-all-providers-are-dummylocationpro)

[Android LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608632/android-locationmanager-getlastknownlocation-returns-null)

[Network provider and GPS provider returning null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597076/network-provider-and-gps-provider-returning-null-values)

**permission**

```
<permission
    android:name="xx.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="xicom.biz.perdiem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyccccccccbvxcbpmFLAZwalBGM" />
......
```

Comment: ... and if you open Google Maps it will show your current position? I assume also that you have set the proper permissions, right?

Comment: Yes, please make sure you have the location permissions in your manifest, and that the device doesn't have location disabled.

Comment: thanks for rplying but i do complete my home work and only problem in grand i dnt know y ???

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761390/location-is-not-getting-in-samsung-phone-if-gps-is-disabled) for the answer, for short

To programmatically kick start your app for "current location" run the following code before you call `getLastKnownLocation`

```
YOUR_APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    }
});
```

Some recommendations for fixing GPSTracker issues may be, to set it as 1 min 1 meter

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 ;
```

Comment: I have implements LocationListener and Override onStatusChanged, onProviderEnabled, onProviderDisabled, onLocationChanged. Bad luck not getting location. Please help me

Comment: I have pasted code http://codepad.org/bXtyUqpr Please check and let me know. What is wrong in that code? please help me

Comment: please please use stackoverflow. this is not the way to ask for help. you already have 800 reputation, use that.

Comment: Are you serious ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293679/android-l istview-item-collapse-while-scrolling is your question dude.

Comment: Then take the time to read other questions to answer your question. Noone has the time for this kinda chat help.

Comment: ok lemme try another answers. main problem is some of device not getting location. Please feel free and help me how to resolve this