# Android listview item collapse while scrolling?

Tags: android, listview

I have created listiem text dynamically. based on the array count. First time view was created successful. while scrolling the listview all items will be collapsed. Some time text view showing repeated.

Below i have attached my adapter code please check the code,

```
  public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<PersonDataclass> list;
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater minflater;
private Viewholder holder;
private TextView[] Textview;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonDataclass> personList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    minflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ctx = context;
    list = personList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view == null) {
        view = minflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new Viewholder();
        holder.count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likecount);
        holder.flow_layout = (FlowLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.flow_layout);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Viewholder) view.getTag();
    }
    try {
        holder.count.setText("Total votes count"
                + list.get(arg0).getPrcnt());
        int leftsize = list.get(arg0).getList().size();
        if (leftsize > 0 && leftsize <= 10) {
            Log.i("TAG", "left votelist if" + leftsize + "arg0" + arg0);
            Textview = new TextView[leftsize];
            for (int j = 0; j < leftsize; j++) {
                String str = "<font color=#409bf8>"
                        + list.get(arg0).getList().get(j).getRtuuname()
                        + "</font> <font color=#74869c>" + "voted"
                        + "</font> <font color=#dd095e>"
                        + list.get(arg0).getList().get(j).getRtval()
                        + "</font>" + ",";
                Textview[j] = new TextView(ctx);
                Textview[j].setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
                Textview[j].setTextSize(9);
                holder.flow_layout.addView(Textview[j]);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "left votelist else" + leftsize + "arg0" + arg0);
            Textview = new TextView[1];
            Textview[0] = new TextView(ctx);
            Textview[0].setText("total rates " + list.get(arg0).getPrcnt());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return view;
}

private class Viewholder {
    private TextView count;
    private FlowLayout flow_layout;
}
 }
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya no i'm not getting any error. while scrolling listitem will changed. Like fitst item have arun voted 8 ,this same text showing fifth item also arun voted 8. this is the problem